# Redis - Safely retrieving a small set of keys in production database

Tags: redis

I don't think there is an answer to this but I'm hoping there is something out there.
In production, using KEYS is a bad practice as it will scan all records ( O(n) ).
If there is a very large number of keys, that can hurt performance.

Assuming there is a very large number of keys in a database, are there any safe ways to get a few of those keys? Eg if I just want to look at a record and I don't really care what I get.

I understand this is more of a design issue (eg use select, use sets) and that I should never really need to run keys unless I know there isn't a huge ammount of data in the database. The motivation is more about being cautious so I don't run keys one day and kill the db because I'm in a different database than I thought

Comment: You should be fine running `keys` in the console, even on a production db. I think the caution is more that you don't want to write code depending on the `keys` method.

Comment: @bgschiller - nope, even in console KEYS is dangerous. The reason for that is that since Redis is (mostly) single-threaded, running long-running commands (e.g. KEYS) can potentially result in a DoS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended approach (as of v2.8) is to use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command (and siblings) instead. SCAN basically allows you to iterate through your keyspace with a cursor so you don't block other operations.

Comment: To address accidentally running KEYS, use the rename command option in Redis' config file to rename or remove (by renaming to an empty string) the KEYS command from servers where it should never be run.